# MySQL COUNT(DISTINCT()) unexpected results

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.0.45 on CentOS 5.1.

`SELECT DISTINCT(email) FROM newsletter`

Returns 217259 rows

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(email)) FROM newsletter`

Returns 180698 for the count.

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(email) FROM newsletter) AS foo`

Returns 180698 for the count.

Shouldn't all 3 queries return the same value?

Here is the schema of the newsletter table

```
CREATE TABLE `newsletter` (
  `newsID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `newsletter` varchar(8) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`newsID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

**Update:** I've found that if I add a `WHERE` clause to the first query then I get the correct results. The `WHERE` clause is such that it will not effect the results.

`SELECT DISTINCT(email) FROM newsletter WHERE newsID > 0`

Comment: I have the same problem, `count(DISTINCT s0_.id)` return `31` result, but `DISTINCT s0_.id` return `26` result, while there is no any duplicate id in result

Answer (score 2):

could you possibly intersect the differing results to see what the extra rows are?

Comment: One of the differing results is an aggregate, how could he do this?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that there are some null values in email column. Try

```
select count(*) from newsletter where email is null;
```

Comment: Moreover, at most that should result in a difference of 1.

Comment: also look for empty string values, a cheat lots of newbie devs use to avoid the NOT NULL clause $string = ''

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, what happens if you change it to "`select distinct(email) from newsletter order by email;`"  I don't think it should make a difference, but it might.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Maglob [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244208/mysql-countdistinct-unexpected-results#244435) you may be getting some NULLs in your email column. Try with something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(COALESCE(email, 0)) FROM newsletter
```

That would give you the results you expect. Oh, wait. The definition says that email does not accept NULL values. If that is truly the case, then it is odd.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that rows were deleted from the table between your two queries.  But I assume you've run these multiple times in various orders so I doubt that's it.

What rowcount do you get from this query:

```
SELECT email FROM newsletter GROUP BY email;
```